# Python SQLite3 search by column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am looking for a way to get a row from a database and every value in it. For example, by searching by `Name` or `ItemNumber` and the code will retrieve the value for `Price` or any other column value in the row. I have tried using this code and it returns every row and values for those rows instead of just 1 as I am looking for.

```
import sqlite3
cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
sqlite_select_query = """SELECT 374932 from ItemLookup"""
cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

I have also used `cursor.fetchone()` and this returns `374932` provided in the `SELECT 374932` from `ItemLookup` code multiple times. Using `fetchmany()` with any `row[0]` or `row[1]` values displays a tuple out of range error message. I have searched the internet and cannot find an explanation for this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your table schema? Also what is wrong with the query `select * from ItemLookup where ...`?

Comment: Select * from ItemLookup returns every row value, not the one I am looking for as far as I know. ItemLookup has columns 'ItemNumber'(The ID essentially) 'Name' 'Price' 'Date' and 'Location'.

Comment: You can use `select * from ItemLookup where ItemNumber=<some value>` to fetch a row with particular item number. If you don't want all the columns of that row mention the columns you want instead of `*`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is EXACTLY the answer I was looking for. Is there any way to convert what was received from the lookup into a list format?

Comment: `rows = cursor.fetchall()` will turn `rows` into a list of rows. In that list, each element will be a tuple of column values

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries generally follow the syntax of
`SELECT field FROM table WHERE condition`
for example, this is a query for Joe's information: `SELECT * FROM ItemLookup WHERE Name = 'Joe'`

You can use this to query the information you want based on specific conditions.